# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I am trying to apply a simple rule on form input. But when i am loading the page it throwing this error.
When i tried to add rules on form by name, it was working fine.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    messages: {
      required: "Required input",
      minlength: "Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      // Place the error message in the specified element
      $("#usernameError").html(error);
    }
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <span id="usernameError" style="color: red;"></span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add validation to the form before you can add rules to the inputs in the form.

You don't call `.validate()` within the submit method. You call it at top-level to declare that the form should be validated; it will add the `submit` listener itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").validate();

  $("#username").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    messages: {
      required: "Required input",
      minlength: "Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      // Place the error message in the specified element
      $("#usernameError").html(error);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <span id="usernameError" style="color: red;"></span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```